# Window Location Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, playframework, routes

I expect the following JavaScript function to redirect to a URL that matches my **routes** file.

```
function getUrl() 
{   
    var hash= $('#hashText').val();

    // When the user has not entered a hash, alert to inform them.
    if (!hash)
    {
        alert("Please enter a hash first.");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Redirecting to ... http://localhost:8080/tasks/" + hash);
        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/tasks/" + hash;
    }
}
```

Here's the corresponding route entry in my **routes** file.

```
GET     /tasks/:hash                controllers.Application.getTask(hash: Int)
```

However, the result of this function is:

`http://localhost:9000/tasks?hash=2014281623`

Answer (score 0):

how about if you change your code to this:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:9000/tasks/';
url += escape(hash);
window.location = url;
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation. But, how can I get a re-direct to `localhost:8080/tasks/<given ID>`? `window.location = "localhost:9000/tasks/" + address` is still redirecting me to `http://localhost:9000/tasks?hash=2014281623`

Comment: Thanks for adding the above comment. how about if you try with encodeURI(uri).

Comment: Even with `encodeURI(uri)`, it's still taking me to `http://localhost:9000/tasks?hash=2014281623`

Comment: did you try the escape command I provided in the answer ? if that does not work then there must be something wrong on the server side.

Comment: Looks like I need to do: `window.location = "/" + hash;` Consider this example: http://jsfiddle.net/dzu6H/3/

Comment: Actually, that didn't work either. Still getting `http://localhost:9000/tasks?hash=2014281623`